# Why can't I signout of Google in iOS?

Tags: ios, google-signin

In iOS, I'm developing Google login using Google SDK. But I can't sign out after sign in. After calling signOut method, there is no any react.
Please help me.

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect];
```

Comment: What reaction are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify it please do the follwing:

When you call [GIDSignin sharedInstance] signOut], the current logged user will be logged out and  try to launch the Google login screen you would see that the user user would be logged out.

But it will show the list of user names and mail ids logged with the device.(As it follows SSO)
and mentioning  "Signed out" at the bottom only if you manually signed out.